# Why I can't access to @ViewChild reference of a div defined in another component (not a subcomponent) in this example?

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular9, viewchild

I am finding some problem trying to use **@ViewChild()** decorator.

I will try to explain in details what I am trying to do.

I have a correctly working version of my project (at the moment it is just a minimal prototype on which I am working on), in case you can see the complete code here: https://bitbucket.org/dgs_poste_team/soc_calendar/src/master/

So basically I have this main **app-component.html** main view:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <app-header></app-header>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <p>DRAGGABLE</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-8">
        <app-fullcalendar></app-fullcalendar>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

As you can see it contains the reference to the **app-fullcalendar** component. This component contain a calendar implementing something like this: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/external-dragging-demo

Where is shown a calendar and an "external events" box where I can pick an event and drag into inside my calendar.

In my original version it works fine but at the moment I implemented it in the following simple way:

1) This is my **fullcalendar.component.html** view file:

```
<p>fullcalendar works!</p>

<div class="content-section implementation">
  <p-fullCalendar #fullcalendar
                  [events]="events"
                  [options]="options">
  </p-fullCalendar>
</div>

<div #external>
  <p>
    <strong>Draggable Events</strong>
  </p>
  <app-people-list></app-people-list>
</div>
```

As you can see it contains a div having reference name set to **external** and this div contain a sub component of my **app-fullcalendar** component that simply renders the event list (**app-people-list**, in my use case an event is a person that I have to put on a specific date of my calendar, but this is not so important now).

Then into the typescript code handling the **app-fullcalendar** component behavior I have this code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { EventService } from '../event.service';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list';
import interactionPlugin, { Draggable } from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import { FullCalendar } from 'primeng';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fullcalendar',
  templateUrl: './fullcalendar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fullcalendar.component.css']
})
export class FullcalendarComponent implements OnInit {

  events: any[];
  options: any;
  header: any;

  //people: any[];

  @ViewChild('fullcalendar') fullcalendar: FullCalendar;
  @ViewChild('external') external: ElementRef;

  constructor(private eventService: EventService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.eventService.getEvents().then(events => { this.events = events;});
    //this.eventService.getPeople().then(people => {this.people = people;});

    //console.log("PEOPLE: " + this.people);

    this.options = {
        plugins:[ dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, listPlugin ],
        defaultDate: '2017-02-01',
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
        },
        editable: true,

        dateClick: (dateClickEvent) =>  {         // <-- add the callback here as one of the properties of `options`
          console.log("DATE CLICKED !!!");
        },

        eventClick: (eventClickEvent) => {
          console.log("EVENT CLICKED !!!");
        },

        eventDragStop: (eventDragStopEvent) => {
          console.log("EVENT DRAG STOP !!!");
        },

        eventReceive: (eventReceiveEvent) => {
          console.log("EXTERNAL EVENT LAND ON THE CALENDAR");
          //console.log(eventReceiveEvent);
          this.eventService.addEvent(eventReceiveEvent);
        }
    };

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    //console.log("ngAfterViewInit() START !!!")

    new Draggable(this.external.nativeElement, {
      itemSelector: '.fc-event',
      eventData: function(eventEl) {
        console.log("DRAG !!!");
        return {
          title: eventEl.innerText
        };
      }
    });

  }

}
```

So in this code I take the reference to the div having reference named **external**, by this line:

```
@ViewChild('external') external: ElementRef;
```

So this external properties contains the reference of this specific div that will contains my list of events\people that I have to drag inside my calendar.

Then I use this reference property inside the **ngAfterViewInit()** to allow the drag and drop of the element shown inside the div having refernce **external**.

ngAfterViewInit() {
    //console.log("ngAfterViewInit() START !!!")

```
new Draggable(this.external.nativeElement, {
  itemSelector: '.fc-event',
  eventData: function(eventEl) {
    console.log("DRAG !!!");
    return {
      title: eventEl.innerText
    };
  }
```

NOTE: the **.fc-class** specified in the item selector is rendered inside the  and it is put on each element of the event\person list rendered.

Perfect it works fine !!!

Now my problem: my idea is that in this way the code is too strongly coupled and I was thingkin to decouple it in this way:

1) The div referenced my **#external** and containing my  rendering the list of people\event that have to be dragged inside my calendar is no more a sub component of my **full-calendar** component but it is at the same level inside my **app-component**.

So basically I remove it from my **fullcalendar.component.html** that become:

```
<p>fullcalendar works!</p>

<div class="content-section implementation">
  <p-fullCalendar #fullcalendar
                  [events]="events"
                  [options]="options">
  </p-fullCalendar>
</div>

<!-- REMOVED -->
<!--
<div #external>
  <p>
    <strong>Draggable Events</strong>
  </p>

  <app-people-list></app-people-list>
</div>
-->
```

And I put it in the left column of my **app.component.html** file, that now is:

Ok now the list of people\events is rendered on the left side but I can't anymore drag the event\person from this list into my calendar. This because in the JavaScript console I am obtaining this error message:

```
core.js:6272 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
    at FullcalendarComponent.ngAfterViewInit (fullcalendar.component.ts:67)
    at callHook (core.js:4770)
    at callHooks (core.js:4734)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:4674)
    at refreshView (core.js:12060)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:13461)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11701)
    at refreshView (core.js:12036)
    at renderComponentOrTemplate (core.js:12114)
    at tickRootContext (core.js:13668)
```

This error happen into the **ngAfterViewInit()** function of the **fullcalendar.app.component.ts** file:

ngAfterViewInit() {
    //console.log("ngAfterViewInit() START !!!")

```
new Draggable(this.external.nativeElement, {
  itemSelector: '.fc-event',
  eventData: function(eventEl) {
    console.log("DRAG !!!");
    return {
      title: eventEl.innerText
    };
  }
});
```

It seems that this component can't retrieve anymore the div with the **#external** reference when this hook is executed. 
I suspect that this happens because this hook function is automatically executed after that Angular have completly rendered the **fullcalendar.app.component** component.

In the first working example it worked because the **app-people-list** was a sub component so this function execution happened after that all the subcomponent was rendered. But now my **app-people-list** is no more a subcomponent and I suspect that this **ngAfterViewInit()** is no more the right solution. Is it this idea correct?

What can I do to solve the situation and have my example correctly working? Have I to use another hook or there is some other good solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ViewChild` ONLY works on things declared in that component's template, not the entire app's template.

but you can pass template refs as inputs no problem...

```
<app-fullcalendar [externals]="externals"></app-fullcalendar>
```

and you can just declare `externals` as an input in full calendar instead of a view child:

```
@Input() externals: ElementRef
```

which you can use as you see fit in `ngOnInit` or later hooks.

however, if I'm reading this correctly, that seems not needed, and all you need to do is move this part:

```
  @ViewChild('external') external: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    //console.log("ngAfterViewInit() START !!!")

    new Draggable(this.external.nativeElement, {
      itemSelector: '.fc-event',
      eventData: function(eventEl) {
        console.log("DRAG !!!");
        return {
          title: eventEl.innerText
        };
      }
    });

  }
```

out of `fullcalendar.component.ts`, and into the `app.component.ts` controller.  since all you're doing with the view child is declaring it as draggable, this should work fine in app component and you don't really need to access it inside full calendar.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use **content projection** to solve this.

So, if I understood correctly, now you have something like this:

#### app.component.html

```html
<!-- ... -->
<app-header></app-header>

<app-fullcalendar></app-fullcalendar>

<div #external>
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

If that's the case, I think you can do this:

#### app.component.html

```html
<app-fullcalendar>
  <div #external>
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</app-fullcalendar>
```

#### app-fullcalendar.component.ts

```js
@ContentChild('external') external: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;

ngAfterContentInit () {
  /* this.external... */
}
```

### EDIT

I think this could work.

#### app.component.html

```html
<!-- Left column -->
<!-- <app-test2 #external></app-test2> -->

<div #external>
  test23112
</div>

<!-- Right column -->
<app-test1>
  <ng-container [share-comp]="external"></ng-container>
</app-test1>
```

#### share-comp.directive.ts

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[share-comp]'
})
export class ShareCompDirective {

  @Input('share-comp') shared: any

  constructor() { }

}
```

#### app-test1.component.ts

*(app.calendar in your case)*

```js
  @ContentChild(ShareCompDirective) private external: ShareCompDirective;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterContentInit () {
    // If the `external` part is a component
    // const nativeElem = (this.external.shared.elem as ElementRef).nativeElement;

    // If the shared part is a DOM element
    const nativeElem = this.external.shared
    console.log(nativeElem)
  }
```

[ng-run demo](https://ng-run.com/edit/ugHTX4axdbWgsPVHTlrX?open=app%2Ftest1%2Ftest1.component.ts)

Comment: mmm no I can't put my div having reference #external inside the <app-fullcaelndar> tag because this div referenced by the #external is in the left column of my Bootstrap theme and the <app-fulcaldenda> is into the right column. They have to be indipendent components

Comment: @AndreaNobili I've updated my answer.

Comment: if you really need to access the externals component inside the calendar component, nothing is stopping you from passing it as an input directly to full calendar component instead of accessing indirectly via a content projected directive.  but, I really don't see why OP needs to access this component inside the full calendar if all they're doing is declaring it a draggable element.

Comment: @bryan60 I agree. However, I chose this approach as it involves less work in the _container_ component, most of the logic is done from the template. Also, if the `app-calendar` needs more components, they can simply be added with that directive.

Comment: `less work in the container` isn't really a reason to structure this way. the logic should be where it belongs. and declaring something draggable probably doesn't belong to the full calendar component as it's restrictive, ie if OP wanted something nested inside the header to be draggable to the calendar, this stops working. Ideally this work would just be delegated to a directive that doesn't care where it is. and the more components argument won't apply here as contentchild only finds one element and you can just pass an array of template refs / add more input

Comment: @bryan60 The problem I was trying to solve was to how to make `A` component available in `B` component, knowing that they are siblings. I didn't consider the actual problem(e.g that it's about a calendar comp with draggable parts), but an abstraction of it. But I agree there are better ways to solve this. Thanks for your input!